# Оптимизация некоторого условия,включающего в себя алгебру логики

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc

Имеется некоторое условие `if (!((ha > hb) && (hx <= hy)))` 
(Саму программу оптимизировал тут https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hGwEhd)
В функции DeMorgan на компиляторе gcc 5.4 упомянутое выше условие интерпретируется в это:

```
        movl    %r14d, %eax
        imull   %ebp
        movl    %r14d, %eax
        sarl    $31, %eax
        sarl    $5, %edx
        subl    %eax, %edx
        imull   $100, %edx, %edx
        subl    %edx, %r14d
        cmpl    %r14d, %ebx
        jle     .L11
        movl    %r13d, %eax
        imull   %ebp
        movl    %r13d, %eax
        sarl    $31, %eax
        sarl    $5, %edx
        movl    %edx, %ebp
        subl    %eax, %ebp
        imull   $100, %ebp, %ebp
        subl    %ebp, %r13d
        cmpl    %r12d, %r13d
        jg      .L11
```

Переменная  ha == ebx

Переменная  hb == r14d

Переменная  hx == r13d

Переменная  hy == r12d

Мне непонятно, почему в неоптимизированном варианте:

```
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cmpl    -8(%rbp), %eax
        jle     .L6
        movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
        cmpl    -16(%rbp), %eax
        jle     .L7
```

Сравнение  проще и действий меньше , тогда как в оптимизированном варианте происходит вообще что-то страшное, можете объяснить,как это работает ?

Comment: Ваш код переплелся с другим кодом в процессе оптимизации. Большинство процитированного кода (все эти `imull`) не имеют никакого отношения к вашим условиям вообще. Это вычисление вашего `rand() % 100`.

Comment: обратите внимание, получение остатка от деления случайных чисел на 100 в оптимизированном варианте выполняется поэтапно. сначала вычисляются ha и hb, проверяются, если условие не сработало, то вычислять значения hx и hy вообще не имеет смысла и код этого и не делает, если не надо

Comment: В неоптимизированном варианте я вижу весь фактически тот же код, включая все эти `imull` и `sarl`, только упорядоченный в другом порядке.